# Updating SharePoint by email

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, incoming-email

Is there a way I can update my SharePoint from emails that are sent to me?  I get support tickets from a form and instead of manually entering them I would like to auto process this task.  The emails contain the basic:

```
 - Name:      John Dowe
 - Email:     blahblah@johndoe.com
 - Date:      2013-12-12
 - Issue:     Could use some help
 - Client Id: 12345
```

I am still fairly new to SharePoint but I do know how to create pages and customize each page.  Any information or where I can read on this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to send emails to a SharePoint 2013 library, but it will not parse out the information in the body of the email.

1. Create a new library List
2. Go to the library Settings page in the far
   right
3. Click the Incoming email settings
4. For incoming email select Yes and set the email address of the list
5. Set the other settings appropriately
6. Click Save

There are some hurdles though.  Email has to be setup correctly in SharePoint and/or your Exchange server.  We have SharePoint 2013 and Exchange 2010.  I can set everything up, but the connection between Exchange and SharePoint is not configured so the process fails.

While the email will be captured by the list item, the body of the email will be trapped in a column.  I would assume you would want to be able to sort by the requester's name or some other information.  (e.g. the email system captures your email in the following columns E-Mail Sender, E-Mail To, E-Mail Cc, E-Mail Subject, Body of the message, and attachments).

I would suggest looking at the form you are using to generate the email and see about connecting that to a SharePoint list so you can put the information like name, email, and date into the proper list columns. It is pretty reasonable to generate a list item using some javascript and a REST call from your form to your SharePoint server.  That way you will have the proper information in the proper columns.  Better yet move your submission form to SharePoint.  :)

How to: Create, Update, and Delete List Items Using JavaScript
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Here are some additional links that I hope help.
Plan incoming email for a SharePoint farm in SharePoint 2013
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263260.aspx

Configure incoming email for a SharePoint 2013 farm
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947.aspx

Answer (score -1):

We have a similar use case, and will be considering this product:

http://www.cloud2050.com/Pages/CaseStudyParseDataFromEmail.aspx

Is has of course the limitation of being client-side based, but for us it might work.

rgs,